# SATA-II Power consumption

Tags: power-consumption

I cannot find a concrete specification on the net on how much current can be drawn from an SATA-II connection. I am sure that the standard specifies that value, but I don´t see the point to buy the whole spec just to know this single value.

Does anyone have values for the average / max. power consumption?

Comment: Check the datasheets of some SATA connectors and use the specified current carrying capabilities on their power pins. I don't think they would specify a value greater than the official spec (there's no point in it), and they can't do lower.

Comment: I am not sure about that. There are highspeed B2B connectors rated for 500mA per pin but nobody needs to drive highspeed interfaces with this high currents per pin. I think that connectors actually can often do much better than what is needed

Comment: I don't understand. I was thinking you were talking about the power pins of the SATA connectors, which must be able to provide enough current to power the *whole hard drive* (including motor and all, not just the interface transceivers). So 500mA seems consistent, once multiplied by the number of power pins. Now, if you're talking about the interface data pins, you are not allowed to draw any significant current from that, and even if the connectors specifies 500mA for them, it's obviously not applicable.

Comment: No, you were right. I mean the power pins. But again, I don´t think that the current rating of the connector pins are in the range of what the standard allows a SATA device to draw. The 500mA were an example and not the value of an SATA connector but from a 0.4mm pitch high speed B2B connector where you would usually drive USB2.0 DATA lines over it (and you would not draw this current from!)

Comment: Also, the SATA-II receptable connector which I have at hand, does not specify currents in the datasheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the specification, but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Power_connectors) states a current of 1.5A per pin.

This is supported by a [datasheet](http://www.molex.com/webdocs/datasheets/pdf/en-us/0679260015_IDT_AND_SOLDER_CON.pdf) from Molex for a power connector where it states 1.5A at 15V DC maximum per pin.

An additional support is [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245941/what-is-the-power-specification-for-sata) where someone, who actually has the specification, is mentioning the 1.5A as well.

Considering the spin-up currents of 3.5" HDDs this doesn't seem to be a far fetched requirement. (I measured around 10W additional power during spin-up)

Now you have three 3.3V, three 5V and three 12V lines, which means you could draw a total of 91.35W from a single SATA power connector, but I'd stay away from maximum specifications.

Comment: Sorry that I missed the question which you referred to -> Thanks for the answer